# Why are all the Blues Brothers Band members jailed?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-blues-brothers

In the final scene of *The Blues Brothers* we see the band that is playing Jailhouse Rock in the jail's dining hall.

In the movie we see that the police is chasing only Jack and Elwood, not the entire band, so why is all the Blues Brothers Band jailed at the end of the movie?

I was wondering if the band is only a visitor, but as we can see they wear the prisoner uniform with relative prisoner number attached to the shirt.

Comment: Maybe they were charged with 'aiding and abetting' Jake & Elwood..

Comment: @andrewthompson - They do commit a wide range of crimes in the movie; harbouring known fugitives and abetting armed robbery and car theft.

Comment: @AndrewThompson - I also always just figured it was for "aiding and abetting". There was also the little matter of that bar tab they all ran out on at Bob's Country Bunker. Grand theft in Illinois right now is at $3,300, but it was probably lower in the 70's. And passing themselves off as another band is probably Fraud.

Comment: Because its funny

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to th[is forum post](http://www.bluesbrotherscentral.com/forum/topic/2076-why-did-the-band-go-to-jail/), there's additional info offered by the movie scrapbook "[Blues Brothers: Private](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Blues-Brothers-Private-Judith-Jacklin/dp/0399504761)". In short, all of the various characters were convicted of different offenses *after* the famous gig.

> *According to Blues Brothers: Private, they all had criminal records.
>   Most of the band were involved in something after the gig, I think it
>   was to do with an underage girl found sleeping in the Magictones car.
>   Bones Malone was found in a field, pretended he had never heard of the
>   Blues Brothers, but they found cannabis on him. Same with Duck Dunn I
>   think. Willie Hall and Matt Murphy were suspected of being involved
>   with the Black Panthers.*

The cannabis possession is also mentioned on the book's [review on amazon](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Blues-Brothers-Private-Judith-Jacklin/dp/0399504761) and [fasthit](http://www.fast-hit.com/isbn-find-book-title/Blues-Brothers-Private_9780399504761).